# How to let software support by java 7 and java 8

Tags: java, version

A software is developed and maintained by Java 1.6 only. (Java 7 and Java 8 can not compile it)
Currently want to let it supported by java 7 and 8.  In case it matters, I work on Windows OS, in the NetBeans IDE.

Is there any easy way?  If not, is there any process I can follow with?

Comment: Can you tell us more as to why java 7 and 8 won't compile it ?

Comment: Why doesn't it compile with Java 7+? On a language level you shouldn't get any problems, so I assume it's a standard library issue.

Comment: Sorry guys. misleading problem. My friend figure that out. It is the advanced installation, which can not identify the java 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code compiled for/against JDK6 runs on higher JRE's, unless your code relies on quirks/glitches specific to a JRE (e.g. using stuff from sun.misc packages). Another problem may be that you have native DLL's only for 32bit, but are trying to run on a 64bit JRE.

Code written for Java6 can generally be compiled using Java7/8, although there *may* be a few specific cases with generics where the code needs slight adaptions (those will result in a compiler error).